# Keras model returning AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I am trying to build a simple Keras model but am getting an AttributeError for some unkown reason. All of the datatypes I am feeding to the model are float64. Code is as follows:

Defining features and target:

`X = rated_df[["content_found", "domain_found","title_found", "url_found",  "CPC","Competition","number_of_results","search_vol"]]`

`y = "Position"`

Model as follows:

`from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense`

`model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))`

`model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])`

Then the fitting of the model which causes the error:

`model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)`

and error is

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim'

A picture of the data is below and as mentioned contains all float64 datatypes:

[image]

If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That pretty much always means something is not of the type expected.  check what args the various `model` methods are expecting and make sure you're passing the right types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining `y` to be a string.

You likely want

```
y = df["Position"]
```

Comment: Indeed, can't believe I missed something so small! Thanks!